# Why will hair not render in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

My hair particle system (beads of water) renders as it should in the viewport, but not in the render, even though the effect is enabled for rendering. Can anyone help?

[BLEND FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12AkTGE2g3i87Hz1nWquaBYz2eZy9xuz5/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The collection of instanced objects were not enabled for rendering. Makes no sense to me why these objects would need to be enabled for rendering when I want to render only the particle system, but I guess that's beside the point.